# Mapping list of strings in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

My entity has besides other properties Keyword property which is of type list of strings.

```
public virtual IList<string> Keywords { get; set; }
```

so I tried to map this property using conformist mapping by code approach simple as possible like this

```
Property(x => x.Keywords);
```

but I'm getting following exception

> NHibernate.MappingException : Could not determine type for:
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0,.....

Comment: How's `Keywords` represented in your database if you don't mind me asking ?

Comment: as text field separated by commas.

Comment: How is your DB model?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria My db model is fine thank you :) What do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Hehehe, as @DimitarDimitrov point, how you represents `KeyWords` in DB, eg: I have a table **Document** with a relation **many to many** with a table **KeyWord**.

Comment: aha, I thought in db to represent keywords as one text field separated by commas. I don't need entity keyword cause I do not want to track keyword by it's identity. Please correct me if there is better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map this to a private `string` field and then use `string.Split` in your `Keywords` getter to get a list.

```
public class MyClass {
    private string _keywords;

    public virtual IEnumerable<string> Keywords {
        get { return _keywords.Split(','); }
        set { _keywords = string.Join(value, ","); }
    }
}
```

I am not familiar with mapping by code that NH uses (I use FluentNH) but your mapping would probably be something like this:

```
Map("_keywords", map => {
    map.Access(Access.Field);
    // ...
});
```

Comment: It's right but use `public virtual string DbKeyWords { get; set; }` instead of `_keyword` or NHibernate cannot map.